# Does anybody knows which is the name of this top tabs in an iphone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

[link text](http://twitpic.com/3a4x9v)

I'm newbie on Iphone Development and I don't know how to find information about this kind of tabs, It seems that the interface builder doesn't supported. Please, any info about how to implement this kind of "top-tabs" could be really cool.

Thks!

Answer (score 2):

That's a `UISegementedControl` inside a `UIToolbar` (or possibly) a `UINavigationController` which has its own toolbar.